# Android layout isn't displayed correctly

Tags: android, forms, layout, android-relativelayout

This is my code. It's just a form. If i started the applycation with my adv (Nexus S), the form is displayed fine, but if i use it with a small screen, it's not shown completely (and i can't scroll down to see the rest of the form). I used dip, but the problem is still here. Why?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            />

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/edit_name"
            />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            />

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/edit_lastname"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_lastname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            />

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/edit_sex"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_sex"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            />

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/edit_age"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_age"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/form_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
            android:layout_width="130dip"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is quite a few `Views` vertically on a small screen. You could create a different `layout` that isn't just vertical for small screens but that wouldn't really be the best way and may not look very good (actually probably wouldn't)

You could wrap the whole thing in a `ScrollView` so that it will scroll when it doesn't all fit on the screen, like with smaller screens.

Or you could use the Android property for this type of form called [android:hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint). Instead of having `TextViews` for the label, you would set a hint in the `EditText`s to tell the user what information to enter. Ex.

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/edit_name"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text=""
     android:hint="@string/edit_message"
     android:hint="Please enter name here"    <!-- see this guy here. Would want to use string resources instead of hard-coded string -->
        />
```

Comment: But why can't it adapt to small screens even if i use dip?

Comment: [This article of the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) should explain it better than I can but just because you use `dp` doesn't mean that you can put as many elements on the screen as you want. Use `ScrollView` or, even better, the `hint` property that I suggested to give the user a better experience

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your LinearLayout in ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout>
    ...
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Does it work for horizzontal scroll too? I can go down now, but i can't go right

Comment: But why can't it adapt to small screens even if i use dip?

Comment: For vertical scrolling use ScrollView or ListView. If you want to scroll horizontally you can use HorizontalScrollView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html